# SP2007 Modify Approval Workflow

Tags: 2007, workflow, sharepoint-designer

Following the completion of the built-in approval workflow, I need to run a second workflow. I'm using the 'wait until field changes' command to monitor the document for the change in approval. When the built-in approval workflow is complete the status changes to Approved, but this actually doesn't update the record so my workflow does not recognize a state change and does not kick off kick off.

Using SPD, is there a way to design a workflow to recognize when the built-in approval workflow is complete?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you have to build your own workflow from scratch in these kinds of situation.

In terms of the built in workflows, they aren't very complicated, so once you have figured out how to create any kind of workflow in SPD, you probably won't find it that much of a challenge.

If building workflows in Shraepoint Designer was as simple as Microsoft suggest in their documentation/marketing, that wouldn't be an issue, and you probably wouldn't be asking the question :-)